# Instagram real time api - manage to get only last uploaded images

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have real time subscription for really popular tag.

My app gets many subscription calls in second and then i am making post request to tag/media/recent, but i am getting duplicate and skipped images because it is very fast. How can i get sure that i request for image that subscription call is sent?

I tried even to set count to 1, and store last min_tag_id, but i am getting duplicates and missed images also.

my idea was to get last picture id, then on subscription call to set sleep for sometime and then call tag/media/recent with count=1 and min_tag_id and i will get picture for that subscription call, but there are still duplicates.

Why Instagram is not simply sending picture ids?

Answer (score 2):

I have been having the same issue as you (working on this over the last week). My workaround, currently, is after Instagram sends a POST that an update for the hashtag has happened, I do a POST call for the most recent photos (currently setting count to 1 as you're doing but still working on getting all the newest photos).

I basically store all the latest photos returned in a database using the photos id as the primary key. If the key already exists in the db I issue an update otherwise the new photo gets inserted into the database. I then check whether an update was called or an insert was called. If an update, I simply exit the function. If an insert was called, I then issue a response to the browser with the new photo (this is very easy to do with web sockets; alternatively you can simply poll your database over a set interval to check if new photos were added).

I'm not even sure if this is a correct approach, it feels very hacky to me but Instagram's real time API is not very intuitive to work with.